# Python: numpy datatypes

Tags: python, numpy, types

I'm currently learning python and numpy for a machine learning project and I'm having difficulty understanding numpy datatypes. I'm doing an exercise that asks me to choose a data type (from this [link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html)) to represent the cases below from this:

A. attendance of this class

B. heartbeat measurements

C. number of votes for a United States of America presidential candidate

I'd create a cell, and write one example for each. The example the exercise gave to capture whether a heads or tails happened in a coin flip is this:

```
np.boolean(True)
```

I'm thinking that for example A. we can use np.boolean(True) as well but I am a bit confused about the application or how to determine numpy datatypes. Any explanation for the examples would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to ask yourself how many different, and which, values you need to represent. This is the difference between data types.

Comment: For example, a heartbeat measurement could have the value 80.7 or 93.65. On the other hand, the number of votes can be 2456 or 2457, but not 2456.17

Comment: And a heartbeat measurement could be 250 at maximum, but a number of votes can be millions.

Comment: Would an unsigned int work for A since it's non-negative and a whole number?

Comment: I see, it helps a lot to think of the set of values possible for a case.